# Deleting a table row from a link inside the <tr>

Tags: jquery

I need help deleting a selected table row using jQuery.

```
<tr data-file='+file_id1+'>
    <td width="40%">'+file_name1+'</td>
    <td>'+upload_date1+'</td>
    <td><a href="sym.php?doc_id='+file_id1+'" class="view2_fl">VIEW FILE</a> | <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="del2_fl">DELETE</a></td>
</tr>
```

When I click on the DELETE link the file is deleted from the db via ajax as follows:-

```
$('.addfile_popup').on('click', '.del2_fl', function(){
var job_id=$(this).data('job');
var file="file_id="+$(this).data('file')+"&job_id="+job_id;
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"admin_includes/del_fl.php",
    data:file,

    success:function(html){
        if(html=="2")
        {
            //delete row

        }
    }
})//end ajax
});
```

My atempts to delete this particular row are causing me problems as I don't seem to be able to locate it using 'this'.

Grateful for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

By default, in the `success` handler, `this` is bound to a mixin of `$.ajaxSettings` and the options you passed to `$.ajax()`.

You can specify the `context` option to bind `this` to the object of your choice, including the value `this` is bound to in the caller. From there, you only need [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to locate the table row to remove:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "admin_includes/del_fl.php",
    data: file,
    context: this,  // Relay 'this' to 'success' handler.
    success: function(html) {
        if (html == "2") {
            // Here, 'this' is the same as in the caller of '$.ajax()'.
            $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: this does work although I think I failed to say that in the same form the user has the ability to add files. If the user adds a file and decides to remove the file then it does not disappear. If the file to remove is duplicated then all files are deleted. (this, however, is down to the mysql which I have now changed). The main problem for me now is deleteing the appended files (I did think using .on() would have solved this.

Comment: That problem is not easy to understand from your comment alone... I would suggest you clarify this by updating your question with more information (posting the code that appends the file would also be a good idea).